# Scale down a Bitmap in WPF with best quality

Tags: wpf, image, bitmap, scale

How can I convert this GDI code to WPF code?

```
Icon bigIcon32x32 = null;
                    bigIcon32x32 = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon("c:\\test.docx");                    

                    Bitmap bm = bigIcon32x32.ToBitmap();

                    Bitmap thumb16x16 = new Bitmap(16, 16);
                    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(thumb16x16);
                    graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                    graphics.DrawImage(bm, new Rectangle(0, 0, 16, 16), new Rectangle(0, 0, bm.Width, bm.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

                    graphics.Dispose();
                    bm.Dispose(); 
                    thumb16x16.Dispose();
```

It seems I have to use the ToBitmap() methode but from then on I want to use WPF only.

In the end I want to display small 16x16 pixel Images in a WPF DataGrid`s Column via Binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show a bitmap in a DataGrid cell you can use a DataGridTemplateColumn with a DataTemplate using the IValueConverter to display an image in a DataGrid cell.

You can play with properties of BmpBitmapDecoder to achieve as good an image as possible.

Here is the definition for the DataGrid in XAML:
1- I have three columns in the DataGrid with the first one being the image.
2- I set Path=. because all I wanted to do was load the image from the converter.
3- The DataGrid binds to a Customers collection in a ViewModel, and I included the definitions of those for completeness at the end.

```
<Window x:Class="ContextMenuNotFiring.Views.MainView"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:Helpers="clr-namespace:ContextMenuNotFiring.Helpers" 
  Title="Main Window" Height="400" Width="800">
  <Window.Resources>
    <Helpers:ImageConverter  x:Key="imgConv"/>
  </Window.Resources>
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid
       Grid.Row="0"
       IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
       Background="Transparent" 
       AutoGenerateColumns="False"
       ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn
           Header="Icon" 
           Width="SizeToHeader">
           <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <Image Source="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource imgConv}}" />
              </DataTemplate>
           </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn 
           Header="First Name" 
           Width="SizeToHeader"
           Binding="{Binding FirstName}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn 
           Header="Last Name" 
           Width="SizeToCells"
           Binding="{Binding LastName}" />
       </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is the converter that does a onetime lookup of the Word Doc's associated icon.
If you want to handle multiple icons store the BitmapFrame references in a Dictionary and use the "value" input parameter to select which image to display.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace ContextMenuNotFiring.Helpers
{
  [ValueConversion(typeof(object), typeof(BitmapSource))]
  public sealed class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
  {
    private static BitmapFrame _bitmapFrame = null;

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                          object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
      try
      {
        if (_bitmapFrame == null)
        {
          using (Icon bigIcon32x32 = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon("c:\\temp\\test.docx"))
          {
            using (Bitmap bm = bigIcon32x32.ToBitmap())
            {
              MemoryStream finalStream = new MemoryStream();
              {
                bm.Save(finalStream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
                BmpBitmapDecoder bitmapDecoder = new BmpBitmapDecoder(finalStream,
                            BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.None);
                _bitmapFrame = bitmapDecoder.Frames[0];

              }
            }
          }
        }

        return _bitmapFrame;
      }
      catch
      {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
      }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
                              object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
  }
}
```

The View Model loads the following collection of Customers my View Model constructor.

```
private List<Customer> _customers = new List<Customer>():
public List<Customer> Customers
{
   get
   {
      return _customers;
   }
}

public class Customer
{
  public String FirstName { get; set; }
  public String LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @Zamboni I have less time now to check that code, but I try it the next weekend. For sure if its good code, I will mark it as solution ;-)

Comment: @Zamboni Where would you create the Dictionary, where I cache the bitmapFrame ? I am using MVVM and I am not quite sure wether I will use a Converter.

Comment: If multiple parts of your code need to use these images then you'll need to move the dictionary to a more global/shared location to make it accessible; otherwise, you should place the dictionary near the code that uses the BitmapFrame.

If you want to control the display of the image from your ViewModel then copy the code in this example to your ViewModel and assign _bitmapFrame to an ImageSource type property from the ViewModel and binding to it from your view.

If the converter is the only place that uses the images I'd likely keep it in the converter.

Comment: A Converter has the purpose to convert one value and return that value. But in your converter you do not even use the VALUE ??? The code does not make sense to me. It looks like a code snippet I found also on SO and its put into the converter without having a context, you understand my concern?

Comment: I've included the full XAML definition of the DataGrid; I hope this helps.